# Display collection document content in the input Firestore Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display data from Firestore in the input field but end up with errors

intem.services.ts

```
getItem(itemId) {
  return this.afs.doc('items' + itemId);
}
```

item.component.ts

```
item;
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private afs: AngularFirestore,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private itemService: ItemService) {

  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  if (id) {this.itemService.getItem(id).snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1), map(p => this.product = p));
}
```

item.component.html

```
<input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="item.title" name="title" type="text" id="title" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Please provide the errors you are getting. A minimum example would be helpful

Comment: ERROR CONTEXT 
Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 13, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} }
IntemFormComponent.html:6:12

Comment: Did you try the fix explained here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879095/angular-4-error-typeerror-error-context-debugcontext

Comment: ERROR
TypeError: _co.item is undefined

Comment: yes but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the data in `ngAfterViewInit() or ngAfterContentInit()`. Also I'm note sure what your data structure looks like but if you have an id and want a single doc, it is `` return this.afs.doc(`items/${itemId}`); ``

Comment: dose not work.  I change code like this:  getItem(itemId) {
 return this.afs.doc(`items/${itemId}`);
} and in my  item.component.ts i change from item; to item = {}; and now i dont get any error but i dont get return data from firestore.  data structure is like items and then auto generated document ID and then i get some info like title:, some description: etc.  In this example i want to displey title

Comment: in my  my-item.component.html i have a link <a [routerLink]="['/my/items', p.id]">Edit</a>  when i click edit  sends me back to items.component with ID od item that a click in the URL, but never get data from firestore itmes in the input fied

Comment: Did you also try taking the `getItem(id)` out of the constructor? Try this `firebase.firestore().collection("items").doc(ItemId).onSnapshot(doc =>{    
      console.log(doc.data())

    })` . Use a makeshift button to click after the component has initialized to check if you get something in the console. You can also use the actual id from firestore to check if the function returns anything.